# Session: Cannot convert int to byte[] in ASP.NET Core 3.0 C#

Tags: c#, session, httpcontext, asp.net-core-3.0

I tried to look up how to use the new way of using sessions in core 3.0.

It goes like:
`HttpContext.Session.Set("UserID", ???);`, except I can't fill in an int.

I tried to look it up on the official microsoft site, but that one only had `HttpContext.Session.SetInt32` or `HttpContext.Session.SetString`.

How do you use the new set from core 3.0?

Comment: int32 is int, if you want the int bytes you can use: BitConverter.GetBytes(myInt);

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, I was able to resolve it like following we need to convert the value of the session variable to byte - array if in case we need to use httpcontext.Session.Set("variable_name", corresponding bytearray of the value)  :

```
public void func(HttpContext httpcontext)
{
          string emailstring = "xyz.com";
          byte[] bytearray= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(emailstring)
          httpcontext.Session.Set("email", bytearray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` only provides `HttpContext.Session.SetInt32` or `HttpContext.Session.SetString`. Check the documentation at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

You can use the following extension methods to set and get any primitive and reference type objects:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);

        return value == null ? default(T) : 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

You can use your choice of `Serialization` technique like `System.Text.Json` or `BinaryFormatter` e.t.c in above extension methods. Check about these extensions method at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0#session-options).

Now to use

```
byte[] bytes = ....
HttpContext.Session.Set<byte[]>(SessionKey, bytes);

byte[] newBytes = HttpContext.Session.Get<byte[]>(SessionKey);
```

Comment: The documentation is wrong and has not been updated for 3.0 correctly